# How to implement a normalization formula in selected columns of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, normalization, data-manipulation

I am doing a personal project with a city data, I am stuck at where I have to normalize the data in order to apply the k-means clustering. I did some digging around and found this formula here:

[image]
Here is the reproducible example

```r
options(scipen = 999)
tract_per_complaints <- data.frame(
                      tract= c(7354, 5036, 17406, 5675, 2354),
                      fire= c(32, 0, 3, 78, 9),
                      flood= c(1, 25, 6, 8,7),
                      noise= c(56, 67, 0, 0, 1), 
                      total_complaints_at_this_tract= c(89, 92, 9, 86, 17),
                      population_at_this_tract= c(34134, 103849, 345300, 43535, 2143767)
                    )

#   tract fire flood noise total_complaints_at_this_tract population_at_this_tract
#1  7354   32     1    56                            89                    34134
#2  5036    0    25    67                            92                   103849
#3 17406    3     6     0                             9                   345300
#4  5675   78     8     0                            86                    43535
#5  2354    9     7     1                            17                  2143767
```

So I wanted to apply the formula above to cells with complaints,`tract_per_complaints[ ,2:4]` only. So I had made a nested `for` loop which didn't work. Then applied the `sweep()` function like so:

```r
sweep(tract_per_complaints[ ,c(2:4)], 1, FUN="/", tract_per_complaints$population_at_this_tract)

#wrong output
#            fire         flood           noise
#1 0.000937481690 0.00002929630 0.0016405929572
#2 0.000000000000 0.00024073414 0.0006451675028
#3 0.000008688097 0.00001737619 0.0000000000000
#4 0.001791661881 0.00018376019 0.0000000000000
#5 0.000004198217 0.00000326528 0.0000004664686
```

Unfortunately this was my best attempt with the problem. What can I try next? I have looked at these:

[Normalization of only one column in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783860/normalization-of-only-one-column-in-data-frame)

[Normalizing columns in R according to a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974196/normalizing-columns-in-r-according-to-a-formula)

[Need help implementing a function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139948/need-help-implementing-a-function-in-r)

[How to use the 'sweep' function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444889/how-to-use-the-sweep-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure `sweep` is the right tool here, as you don't have a summary statistic to sweep out yet. You can do this with `apply`:

```
apply(tract_per_complaints[ ,c(2:4)], 2, 
      FUN=function(v, p) { v * p / sum(v * p)}, 
      p = tract_per_complaints$population_at_this_tract)
```

Output:

```
          fire       flood     noise
[1,] 0.04401224 0.001701866 0.1735655
[2,] 0.00000000 0.129443578 0.6317793
[3,] 0.04174017 0.103296596 0.0000000
[4,] 0.13682627 0.017364677 0.0000000
[5,] 0.77742131 0.748193282 0.1946551
```

As an alternative, you could also look at `dplyr::mutate_at`.

Comment: This is 100X better than what I had done with my for loop. Thank you Marius! Appreciate your help buddy, and I will definitely look at the mutate_at function :)

Comment: Hello, I got it to work with dplyr too: `func <-function(v) { 
            p = tract_per_complaints$population_at_this_tract;
            v * p / sum(v * p)
        }` then `tract_per_complaints <- dplyr::mutate_at(tract_per_complaints,
                 .vars = vars(fire, flood, noise),
                 func)` Thank you again for your great help friend!